# After my questions is closed and deleted - is the reputation lost from downvotes returned?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reputation, deleted-questions

Sorry I can't link to the question.  I knew going in that I would get a few down-votes because the question was a little abstruse.  I was willing to take my lumps.  However, when the thread was removed, I got my points back.  I wasn't expecting that.  I that a normal result?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is relevant for this thread, but it seems to be this link: [The One is Silent. Why?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192293/the-one-is-silent-why) (only visible for 10k+ users and mods)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, what is ironic is that the thread is behaving (to me who can't see it) like the "one" I was describing on the thread. It's like the gorilla in the basketball game. We are so intent on watching the basketball that we don't see the gorilla.  We are so intent on looking at the interesting math that we don't see the significance of the one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. When a post is deleted any down or upvotes are removed.

Comment: The reputation from *upvotes* is sometimes still kept after the deletion, see here: [Does reputation change if an answer gets deleted due to deletion of original post by vote(s)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31176#31177) and [Do you lose the reputation (points) you acquired from a question if/when it is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13762#150096) Namely, if the post has score three or higher and if it was visible for 60 days. (The question was mainly about downvotes, but since you mentioned also upvotes, it seemed reasonable to mention also this exception.)