# If I delete my own downvoted question or answer will I regain lost reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I lose reputation for a statement that's deemed to be of poor quality. I suppose I could delete it to prevent further downvotes. If I do, do I also regain what I lost?

Comment: Yes. It will probably take a few minutes for the reputation to update.

Comment: See also: [Question about post that was closed and deleted.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5089).

Comment: A recent related question: [If I post a question or an answer, which gets upvotes, and I delete said post do I lose reputation?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31944)